# Microsoft Edge rendering issue with scrollable div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, microsoft-edge

I have an interesting CSS / rendering issue with Microsoft Edge and scrollable content in divs that I'm trying to find a workaround for.

If the Edge browser window starts small enough that the div scrollbar is needed immediately, then most(!) of the time the scrollbar will be rendered correctly as below:

[image: Edge rendering correctly]

However if the browser window is resized or the content within the div changes so that a scrollbar is required, rendering of the scrollbar and parent div is performed incorrectly as shown below:

[image: Edge rendering incorrectly]

I've only observed this issue in Edge so far so believe it's an Edge only peculiarity.

Here's the url if you'd like to try it out: https://www.topomap.co.nz/#ShareMap

The CSS for the div is:

```
.sidebar-scrollable-area {
    position: absolute;
    width: 235px;
    top: 38px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Setting `overflow` to either `auto` or `scroll` results in the same issue manifesting.

Does anyone have any ideas that I can try as a fix / workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an Edge specific rendering bug. I'm currently porting the site from Google Maps to Leaflet which gave me a chance to observe that the rendering issue seems to capture a static snapshot of whatever content is under the div when the issue occurs.

As a result I've lodged an error report with Microsoft:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17459668/

The screenshot below demonstrates the rendering issue:

[image]